# How can I open the VST instrument window in Cubase?

Tags: vst, cubase

I'm a cubase newbie and I wonder how I open the instrument window for my VST instrument? I want to open the window for an instrument track, the window where I can use filter knobs and the GUI for the software synth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Tutorial Video on Cubase VST](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZqMlZ69Buwc)!

Check out 3.20 - the **Edit Instrument** button is the button you want to press.